# Max transfer size in SG_IO/SG_ATA_16

Tags: hard-disk, read, scsi, sata, ioctl

I need to pass a direct, raw ATA request to a hard drive (0x25, `READ DMA EXT`), to disobey max sector count (long story), and to bypass all possible OS caches, buffers, reorderings et al.

`HDIO_DRIVE_TASKFILE` IOCTL is no longer available due to `libata`.

I accomplished the goal with a `SG_IO` IOCTL with ATA pass-through (`SG_ATA_16`). Works perfectly except one problem: I can read a maximum of 8192 sectors in one command. I *need* to read a full of 32767 sectors.

- **max_hw_sectors_kb** is 32767, so the drive *supports* this much transfer
- **max_sectors_kb** was low, yet I brought it up to 32767 sectors, to no avail
- **scheduler** is set to *noop*, no change.
- Tried gather buffer (`iovec_count>0`, properly set `iovecs` to consecutive buffer slices), no change.

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04/16.10/17.04/17.10 with standard kernels, SATA drive connected to standard AHCI interface on Intel chipset.

No matter what I do, starting with 8193 sectors, IOCTL bails out with "*Invalid argument*" error (precisely, with `EINVAL` errno). On another machine, it varies slightly from run to run (no reboot), usually settling at max 1344 sectors.

Where to look? What can cause a data transfer cap?

Comment: Now I'm very curious: **Why** do you need to read 32767 sectors at once?

Comment: Can't go into much detail - device on the other end will not be a HDD, it just responds to enough ATA commands to be recognized as HDD. The main operation is `READ DMA EXT`, which delivers a block of data I need, unique for specific starting LBA. I can't allow missed, cached or out-of-order read.

Comment: Well, I gave up Linux. FreeBSD with `MAXPHYS` kernel option bumped-up, merrily conveys 32MB of data at once, using CAM subsystem (code based loosely on `scsicmd()` function of `camcontrol(8)` utility).